# React and webpack dev server

Tags: reactjs, webpack-dev-server

I have a React app. After ejecting, I get the configuration files of webpack.
Where exactly do I have to add some config changes for `Webpack dev server`?
There are two files:  `webpack.config.js` and `webpackDevServer.config.js`.
I tried:

```
module.exports = function(proxy, allowedHost) {
  return {
    port:9000,
    disableHostCheck:
      !proxy || process.env.DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK === 'true',
    // Enable gzip compression of generated files.
    compress: true,
     ...
```

for `webpackDevServer.config.js` and

```
module.exports = function(webpackEnv) {
  const isEnvDevelopment = webpackEnv === 'development';
  const isEnvProduction = webpackEnv === 'production';
  ...
  return {
    mode: isEnvProduction ? 'production' : isEnvDevelopment && 'development',
    devServer: {
    port: 8008
    }, 
     ...
```

for `webpack.config.js` but none works...

Answer (score 0):

You have to make changes to your **package.json** file.

```
 "start": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon ./bin/www",
 "webpack": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development"
```